# Defining Hecke-Algebra via Generators and Relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, knot-theory, hecke-algebras

Given a field $K$ and an element $q \in K$ one can define the Hecke-Algebra $H_n(q)$ ($n \geq 2$) by the generators $1, g_1, ..., g_{n-1}$ and the relations

(1) ...

(2) ...

(3) $g_i ^2 = (1-q)g_i +q$, $1 \leq i \leq n-1$.

I do not understand how to interpret "$+q$" in the third relation: q is no element of the Hecke-Algebra, so how can we add it to $g_i$?

Comment: Identify $1$ with the identity maybe? Then $q = q \cdot \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: So that's the answer?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Alternatively, since this is to be an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$ it is the image of $q$ under the structural morphism.